# Remove one or many members from Object in powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell, object

I have created a custom object called `$info` and moving it to an array `$arr` , 
How is it possible to remove one member along with its all properties ?

My script:

```
Get-Process  | ForEach-Object{ 
    $info = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
    $info | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name Process -Value $_.processname
    $info | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name ID -Value $_.id
    $arr +=  $info
}

$arr | ft -AutoSize
```

The result looks like this :

```
Process                           ID
-------                           --
ApplicationFrameHost           38556
AppVShNotify                    9792
armsvc                          2336
atieclxx                        6944
atiesrxx                        1844
audiodg                        59432
CcmExec                         3988
chrome                         46068
```

How can I remove one particular member for example  "audiodg  59432" gets removed

```
audiodg                        59432
```

Comment: FWIW - when you use `ft` to format it you are effectively deleting all properties associated with it so if you need to call them just make sure the format is the last thing you do with that object.

Answer (score 4):

Your terminology is a bit incorrect here. A member is on an individual object. When you use `Add-Member` above you're adding properties to each individual object, then you're returning an array of objects.

You're asking how to remove an individual object from the array.

In PowerShell you cannot remove an item from an array. You could instead filter the array based on some criteria and create a new one:

```
$newArr = $arr | Where-Object { $_.Name -ne 'audiodg' }
# or
$newArr = $arr | Where-Object { $_.ID -ne 59432 }
```